# Transformations on data.table seems to take longer than on data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a big dataframe (`mydata`) (5.2G: 6000rows, 230,000 columns) from which I need to subset some columns whose names match the values in column  `Name` in the annotation file (`annot`), than convert it into a `matrix`. I read that data.tables are supposed to be much faster, so I am trying to convert my script to handle `mydata` as `data.table` instead of `data.frame`.

So far I don't have the impression that the processing speed is improved when I convert the original data into data.table and *I am trying to understand why*.

## Some example data:

```
mydata=read.table(text="IID A   B   E   G   H   W   Z   D   N   K
                  1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  2 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  3 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  4 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  6 0   0   2   0   2   0   0   0   1   1
                  7 0   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  8 0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  9 0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   1   0
                  10    1   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   2
                  11    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  12    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  13    2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   1
                  14    0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0
                  15    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  16    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
                  17    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  18    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  19    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  20    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0",h=T)

annot=read.table(text="Name Gene
                 A  Gene1
                 B  Gene2
                 E  Gene3
                 G  Gene4
                 H  Gene5
                 W  Gene6
                 Z  Gene7
                 D  Gene8
                 N  Gene9
                 K  Gene10",stringsAsFactors=F,h=T)

genes = c("Gene2","Gene4","Gene9")
```

## Sample code:

```
#as DATA FRAME    
start <- proc.time()
annot1 = annot[which(annot$Gene %in% genes),]
mydata1=mydata[,c(1,which(colnames(mydata) %in% annot1$Name))]
mydata1=mydata1[order(mydata1$IID),]
genomxwork=as.matrix(mydata1[,2:dim(mydata1)[2]])
df_time <- proc.time() - start
df_time
> utilisateur     système      écoulé 
>        0.00        0.00        0.24
```

Same code but this time `mydata` is transformed into `data.table`:

```
#as DATA TABLE
mydataDT=as.data.table(mydata)
annotDT=as.data.table(annot)

start <- proc.time()
annotDT1 = annotDT[which(Gene %in% genes),,]
mydataDT1=mydataDT[,c(1,which(colnames(mydataDT) %in% annot1$Name)),with=F]
mydataDT1=mydataDT1[order(IID),,]
genomxworkDT=as.matrix(mydatDT1[,2:dim(mydataDT1)[2]])
dt_time <- proc.time() - start
dt_time
> utilisateur     système      écoulé 
>        0.00        0.00        0.25
```

In the example the difference is obviously barely remarkable, but on my real data goes up pretty fast when I have few thousands of columns to extract.

This was for 90,000 columns:

```
df_time
> utilisateur     système      écoulé 
>       10.91        0.91       12.02

dt_time
> utilisateur     système      écoulé 
>       24.00        0.00       24.15
```

Comment: Use package microbenchmark for proper benchmarking. Anyway, data.table is optimized for many rows, not for a huge number of columns. Also, your data.table code could probably be also optimized further.

Comment: With just 20 rows of data even a proper benchmark wouldn't be very informative

Comment: Sorting and converting to matrix (apparently for no good reason) are slow... It is not at all clear that the slowdown you identify is related to the column-selection part.

Comment: @Frank the code is just a segment from a bigger script, I need to do all those extractions and transformations so later I can use the resulting matrix for my analysis. What I am trying to do at this point is trying to figure out weather it makes sense to stop using dataframes and replace them with data.tables

Comment: Try matrices...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have updated the post trying to make my question more precise.

Answer (score 1):

The various comments suggested

- to use the `microbenchmark` package,
- to improve the `data.table` code,
- and to use matrices.

(In addition, general concerns were raised regarding the small size of the data set used for benchmarking and the layout of the production data set with 40 times more columns than rows.)

However, I've repeated the benchmark using `microbenchmark` with

1. the original data.frame code of the OP,
2. the original data.table code of the OP,
3. a streamlined data.table version,
4. a streamlined data.frame version,
5. a matrix version.

#### Results

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
 df_orig  192.944  218.2420  235.02202  225.7940  236.9325  394.950   100
 dt_orig 1012.672 1038.1590 1104.42052 1063.2675 1093.2855 3483.561   100
     dt2  962.454  984.7315 1040.32245 1001.3445 1026.8315 3130.523   100
     df2   47.953   53.2400   64.45366   63.0565   65.6995  217.109   100
     mat    2.644    4.5310    6.46469    6.4190    7.1750   51.352   100
```

With the *given small data set of 20 rows and 11 columns*, the matrix version is ten times faster than the streamlined data.frame version which is about 4 times faster than the original data.frame version. For this simple data retrieval task, the strongpoints of `data.table` e.g., update without copying, aren't used. So, it's no wonder that overhead is dominating for this toy example.

#### Benchmark code

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  df_orig = {
    annot1 = annot[which(annot$Gene %in% genes),]
    mydata1=mydata[,c(1,which(colnames(mydata) %in% annot1$Name))]
    mydata1=mydata1[order(mydata1$IID),]
    genomxwork=as.matrix(mydata1[,2:dim(mydata1)[2]])
  },
  dt_orig = {
    annotDT1 = annotDT[which(Gene %in% genes),,]
    mydataDT1=mydataDT[,c(1,which(colnames(mydataDT) %in% annot1$Name)),with=F]
    mydataDT1=mydataDT1[order(IID),,]
    genomxworkDT=as.matrix(mydataDT1[,2:dim(mydataDT1)[2]])
  },
  dt2 = {
    genomxworkDT <- as.matrix(mydataDT[
      , .SD, .SDcols = annotDT[J(genes), on = "Gene"]$Name])
  },
  df2 = {
    genomxwork <- as.matrix(mydata0[, names(annot_vec)[annot_vec %in% genes]])
  },
  mat = {
    genomxwork <- mat[, names(annot_vec)[annot_vec %in% genes]]
  },
  times = 100L
)
```

#### Data

The data conversion to data.table and matrix, resp., is done outside of the benchmark as this probably would be also the case in the production setting.

```
mydata=read.table(text="IID A   B   E   G   H   W   Z   D   N   K
                  1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  2 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  3 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  4 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  6 0   0   2   0   2   0   0   0   1   1
                  7 0   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  8 0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  9 0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   1   0
                  10    1   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   2
                  11    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  12    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  13    2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   1
                  14    0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0
                  15    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  16    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
                  17    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  18    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  19    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                  20    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0",h=T)
mydataDT=as.data.table(mydata)
mat <- as.matrix(mydata[order(mydata$IID), ])

annot=read.table(text="Name Gene
                 A  Gene1
                 B  Gene2
                 E  Gene3
                 G  Gene4
                 H  Gene5
                 W  Gene6
                 Z  Gene7
                 D  Gene8
                 N  Gene9
                 K  Gene10",stringsAsFactors=F,h=T)

annotDT=as.data.table(annot)
annot_vec <- setNames(annot$Gene, annot$Name)

genes = c("Gene2","Gene4","Gene9")
```